# Can low battery cause car to cut out?

Tags: battery, starting, corrosion

Honda Civic vti 1999.

Car starts and cuts out immediately. On a few occadions it has started on stayed on for longer e.g 30 seconds to 1 minute but it still cuts out again.

The battery is showing 12.15 without starting.  Could this cause the above?

When using the multimeter i noticed that I have to connect to the very silvery parts to get a reading and the darker parts of the terminals do not give a reading.  I’m assuming they are cirroded(see pics).  Could this cause said issue?

Also holding the ignition causes it to stay on but this does not have the same staying on sound as a faulty ignition switch which I replace earlier.

Could a low battery or corroded terminals cause this? Car had been idle for sometime.  Any other ideas?

Just to add mechanic(who are not very competent around here) sounds like a fuel starvation issue.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Clean and treat the battery terminals. But it is not likely to be the real issue.

Comment: Yes, that severe corrosion can cause all kinds or weird problems. Remove and Clean them as suggested

Comment: What does “ Also holding the ground ignition ” mean?

Comment: @HandyHowie sorry typo.

Answer (score 1):

It may or may not be the problem, but you really should remove battery cables and thoroughly clean them and battery posts and top of battery.  Then you should properly charge the battery, then have it tested. Then if it's good, reinstall it (or a new battery if it tested bad) and then with the car running, check your voltage at the battery. You should have 14 volts or more. Either way you must start diagnosis with a healthy battery and clean connections.